# Django NoReverseMatch error on production

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-errors

When I run my code in django local server by "python manage.py runserver" everything works fine  but when I run it in pythonanywhere server I get NoReverseMatch error. I am using git and pulled all the code from there but I checked all the code and it is the same that in my computer which works fine. Can someone say what is wrong? Thanks

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'post_create' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404,redirect
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm

    # Create your views here.
    def post_list(request):
        posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
        return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

    def post_detail(request,pk):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})


    def post_create(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            forms = PostForm(request.POST)
            if forms.is_valid():
                post = forms.save(commit=False)
                post.author = request.user
                post.published_date = timezone.now()
                post.save()
                return redirect('post_detail',pk = post.pk)

        else:
            forms = PostForm()
        context = {'forms': forms}
        return render(request, 'blog/post_create.html',context)

    def post_edit(request,pk):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            forms = PostForm(request.POST,instance = post)
            if forms.is_valid():
                post = forms.save(commit=False)
                post.author = request.user
                post.published_date = timezone.now()
                post.save()
                return redirect('post_detail',pk = post.pk)
        else:
            forms = PostForm(instance=post)
        context = {'forms': forms}
        return render(request, 'blog/post_create.html',context)
```

**blog/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_create, name='post_create'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),

]
```

**mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',include('blog.urls'))
]
```

Comment: Have you double checked that both Django and Python versions are the same in both environments?

Comment: @Selcuk I double checked django versions by django.get_version () in my computer it is 1.9 in the server 1.9.2

Comment: Have you set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable? With the proper ROOT_URL_CONF in it?

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes it is ok. The site was working before the last git pull where I added post creating function.

Comment: Can you show your installed apps from the settings on the server?

Comment: What is the version of django you are using?

Comment: Did you reload the website on the "Web" tab in PythonAnywhere after you pulled the code?

Comment: for `nginx+gunicorn`: restarting the `gunicorn` solved my problem. Make sure that you are restarting the right gunicorn service (I was driving myself insane until I realized I was restarting the wrong service) `sudo systemctl restart your_gunicorn.service`